# Pandas: How to manipulate two columns and segment in different groups?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of patients and their diagnosis:

```
    date                    patient_id  clinical_evaluation
0   2019-08-26 13:32:43.019162  8430       no
1   2019-11-15 17:55:11.364877  8430       no
2   2019-10-07 18:23:29.611351  14338      yes
3   2019-11-04 20:16:28.610965  14338      no
4   2019-12-02 20:56:55.966354  14338      no
```

Here a patient took a diagnosis test in separate days. Sometimes he needed further evaluation, sometime he didn't. I want to segment those patients in three separate groups:

1. Patients who never needed any further evaluation (only 'no' but not 'yes').
2. Patients who directly went to the further evaluation (only 'yes').
3. Patients who needed both--in one occasion no and in another yes.

I was trying the following code but it seems there would be better ways to do that.

```
df_yes = df[df['clinical_evaluation'] == 'yes']
df_no = df[df['clinical_evaluation'] == 'no']
df_yes.loc[df_yes.patient_id.isin(df_no.patient_id)]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your first two methods, better even than both answers imo. Only thing you could do differently is your last line: `df.groupby('patient_id')['clinical_evaluation'].transform('nunique').gt(1)`

Answer (score 1):

We can do it with `crosstab`, the use this new output as condition matrix

```
Ptype=pd.crosstab(df['patient_id'], df['clinical_evaluation'])

df_yes = df[df['patient_id'].isin(Ptype.index[Ptype['yes'].ne(0) & Ptype['no'].eq(0)])]
df_no = df[df['patient_id'].isin(Ptype.index[Ptype['yes'].eq(0) & Ptype['no'].ne(0)])]
df_both = df[df['patient_id'].isin(Ptype.index[Ptype['yes'].ne(0) & Ptype['no'].ne(0)])]
```

---

If we would like to split them into different tag , the type have three category `noyes, no , yes`

```
df['type']=df['patient_id'].map(Ptype.ne(0).dot(Ptype.columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can groupby and get unique values:

```
df.groupby("patient_id").clinical_evaluation.unique()
```